# Implementing Generic Service for CRUD operations using EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I've done multiple projects using the Repository pattern(Interface=>Repository)but now, I'm facing a new challenge(not a big one) with one of my coworker's code. We are implementing a Generic service that contains all of the CRUD operations methods for all entity classes.

We are using Database first in this project, and have the following structure,

> aspx.cs > entityclass(AppUser) > Generic Service > Entity model.

```
   public class UserServices : GenericServices<User>
   { //Implemented methods }
```

And this as the Generic Service:

```
public class GenericServices<T> where T : class
{
    App_dbEntities _db;
    IDbSet<T> ent;

    public GenericServices()
    {
        _db = new App_dbEntities();
        ent = _db.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Select()
    {
        return ent;
    }

    public T Select(string id)
    {
        ??
    }
}
```

I'm trying to handle the entities's properties but since this is Generic, it doesn't know what entity am handling at the moment. I've seen some examples using predicate as a function parameter. Please give me a hand.

Comment: you can use the `Find` method of the IDbSet interface : `return ent.Find(id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want flexibility and are willing to use expressions as your predicate

```
public virtual T Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _dbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var service = new AppUserServices();
var appUser = service.Select(s=> s.CompositeKey1 == "some_value" && s.CompositeKey2 == "some_other_value");
var appUser2 = service.Select(s=> s.IntProperty == 100 && s.AnotherStringProperty == "some_other_value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @Thomas, you can use `Find` method as I show below:

```
public virtual T Select(params object[] keyValues)
{
  return ent.Find(keyValues);
}
```

This way you can also find entities with composite primary keys.
I suggest to take a look to this [codeplex project](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/), you will find an implementation of *Repository*, *UnitOfWork*, and also *Service* pattern. It's going to give you good ideas.